# Set theory - why there are complement operation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Why there are complement operation if it's basically the same operation as difference?

Comment: set minus and complement are not the same. Typically there is an ambient space say $U$ then $A,B$ live inside of $U$ and complement corresponds to being with respect to the ambient space.

Comment: Short answer, because it's useful to. Long answer, once a universe of discourse is established, it's much easier to write long set algebra proofs, etc. by writing $A^C$ a bajillion times, rather than $U\setminus A$.

Comment: I take it you are talking about $A\setminus B = A\cap B^c$?  Indeed both $x\in A$ AND $x\notin B$ define both the sides of the equation.  Each can be useful in different contexts.  E.g. $C \cap C^c,$ resembles $c \land \lnot c$ in logic.  There a many similarities/comparisons between elementary set theory and proposition logic, and even beyond.

Answer (score 1):

To see why they are different, let $U=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ be our ambient space. Let $A=\{2,4,6,8\}$ $B=\{1,3,4,5\}$

Then $A^c = \{1,3,5,7,9\}$ while $A \setminus B = \{2,6,8\}$ these sets are not the same.

Comment: If U does not exist, then $A^c \cap B = B\cap A^c = B\setminus A$.

Comment: true, but typically speaking in any elementary set theory course you work with a general ambient spaces it always makes sense to mention your parent or ambient or universal space (whichever term you prefer lol)

Comment: Understood.   Wasn't here to "nitpick", just to show how context can  alter whether or not two set operations are equivalent.

Comment: lol I hear u :) cheers.

Answer (score 1):

$A, B\subseteq X$
.

Then, $A^c_X=\{x\in X : x\notin A\}$

Now, \begin{align} A\setminus B &=\{x\in A: x\notin B\}=A\cap (X\setminus B) \end{align}

For, $A^c_X = X \cap (X\setminus A) =X\setminus A$

Hence, $A^c_B =B \setminus A$

For the operation of complement the underlying set $X$ plays an important role.

Here you can see the difference, Set difference $A\setminus B $ and complement of $B$ relative to $A$ are indeed same but not same with the complement  relative to the mother set(loosely speaking, Universal Set!).

Comment: You are assuming a "father set", which might me A, or B, or A\cup B

Comment: In the very fast line, I assume $A, B\subset X$, i.e $X$ is here mother set(Universal set).

Comment: If A and B are disjoint, interestingly, $A\setminus B = A.

Comment: I saw that, I just was having fun with a fatherset U, which might actually be such that $A=U, $ or $B= U$,  else $A\cup B= U$.

Comment: Understood.   Wasn't here to "nitpick", just to show the asker how context can  alter whether or not two set operations are equivalent.